# комбинирование интервалов SQL

Tags: sql

Есть некая таблица исходных данных со следующей структурой колонок (N-номер замера с начала года + 300 колонок результаты замера).
По ней в дальнейшем требуется многократно получать статистические данные за определенный интервал замеров. Например, определять сколько за интервал с 10 по 472 замер по каждой из колонок данных было уникальных значений, среднее, максимальное минимальное значение и пр.
Для оптимизации получения(чтобы не рассчитывать значения каждый раз) создана таблица `КэшСтатистики` с колонками `НачальныйЗамер`, `КонечныйЗамер` + `Статистические_данные` за диапазон.
При получении данных с 10 по 472 замер они сразу берутся из таблицы `КэшСтатистики`, а если нужны значения например с 8 по 478 замер их можно посчитать сразу по таблице исходных данных, либо взять просчитанные результаты из `КэшСтатистики` за диапазон 10..472 и агрегировать с оставшимися замерами 8, 9, 473..478.

Вопрос в том, как построить запрос, который бы выдавал максимальную комбинацию рассчитанных интервалов за заданный диапазон замеров из таблицы `КэшСтатистики` чтобы меньше обсчитывать исходных данных

Answer (score 2):

В общеv виде как нибудь так:

```
select col1, col2, ...
  from Кэш
 where "НачальныйЗамер">=$start
   and "КонечныйЗамер" <=$end
union all
select col1, col2, ...
  from "Данные"
  left join (
             select "НачальныйЗамер", "КонечныйЗамер"
               from Кэш
              where "НачальныйЗамер">=$start and "КонечныйЗамер" <=$end
            ) A
    on "Данные".N between A."НачальныйЗамер" and A."КонечныйЗамер"
 where "Данные".N between $start and $end
   and "Данные".N and A."НачальныйЗамер" is null
```

`$start` и `$end` диапазон за который нужны данные. Только никто не сказал, что это будет быстрее, чем работа по исходным данным. Пробуйте, смотрите планы выполнения. Для разных СУБД может быть можно придумать более оптимальные варианты.

И еще интересно что такое "и прочее" в перечислении "максимальное, минимальное, среднее". Далеко не все показатели можно посчитать по уже собранным данным. Какое нибудь средневзвешенное по кешу вы не получите.